# generating html in php the reusable way

Tags: php

I am trying to produce html via php for user comments. I am not using any templates, just plain php. However, I want to write the code the way to use it in multiple pages. 
I tried to keep the user comments generation code in separate page and then include that page. the problem with this approach is that I can't pass parameter (querystring) in `include` directive. 
I tried to write a function from where I returned a long long `html` string. Which did not look very nice thing to do. 
What else is on the menu to make the code reusable and neat if possible.

Comment: You're asking about templating systems. No matter what everyone else will recommend, PHP already **IS** a templating system. Anything else is just yet another layer of templating stuck on top of templates on top of templates... in other words, everyone wants to be Xzibit and "yo dawg" their code.

Comment: @MarcB .. so what are yo saying???

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.  Yes, this question is a little light on details, but the OP explains that they've tried string building with ugly results.  I don't think this necessarily merits downvotes.

Comment: @SuperJer This is what that renders stackoverflow the place of regrets..

Comment: To call PHP a templating system is a bit of an oversimplification.  PHP has long since grown from it's simple templating roots into a fully fledged programming language with many more uses than simply assembling web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1: Output via function**

It is possible to write html with a function without building strings.  Note that calling this function will output the html without returning it, so there is no need to `echo DrawComment(blah, blah);`, simply call it.

```
<?php

//assuming your comments are in an array like array('user'=>$username, 'text'=>$comment)
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    DrawComment($comment['user'], $comment['text']);
}

function DrawComment($user, $comment) {
    ?>
        <h1><?=htmlspecialchars($user);?></h1>
        <p><?=nl2br(htmlspecialchars($comment, ENT_QUOTES));?></p>
    <?php
}
```

**Method 2: Output via include**

You may also include within a loop where the include assumes certain things about pre-existing variables.  This may be a little uglier, but it separates the html from the bulk of the application code.

```
//Application code
<?php
//assuming your comments are in an array like array('user'=>$username, 'text'=>$comment)
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    $user = $comment['user'];
    $text = $comment['text'];
    include('commentHTML.php');
}
```

And the included file:

```
<!--commentHTML.php  Assumes $user and $text are already defined-->
<h1><?=htmlspecialchars($user);?></h1>
<p><?=nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES));?></p>
```

When you include a file, all variables present in the scope which the include was called are available to the included script.  This is a matter of preference for maintainability, but you need to make sure wherever the include is reused, that your variables are set up correctly before it.

Comment: HA!!!!! This is good because it seems the lonely solution but is not this code renders php funny??? I am basically coming from .net environment so this would never ever happen there.. :D

Comment: Combined this with my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have idea how you can get comment. Do it with jQuery and ajax)

```
<div id="comments"></div>    
<script>
    $.ajax({
    url:"comments.php",
    type:"post",
    data:{user_id:"<?php echo $user_id; ?>"}
    success:function(data){
        $('#comments').html(data);
    })
</script>
```

in comments.php check for $_POST['user_id'] and do some actions) Good luck)
Please use DB man)

Comment: Yes  that is what I thought too .. but I wanted to explore the limits of php.. Thanks

Comment: This would work in conjunction with the other answers, as it still assumes that PHP is building the HTML.

Comment: Yes I am employing this approach to inset and edit and delete the comments.. but on initial load I want pure php to do it for me..